# Include class Name in WCF Json Serialization

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

This must be trivial but I can't seem to get it done. Given the following data contract class:

```
public class SampleItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

when deserialized to JSON by my WCF service, provides the following output:

```
[{"Id":1,"StringValue":"Hello"}]
```

Is there any way to include the class name too? i.e.:

```
"SampleItem": [{"Id":1,"StringValue":"Hello"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
private dynamic AddClassName(SampleItem item)
{
      return new {SampleItem = item};
}
```

And

```
var item = new SampleItem {Id = 1, StringValue = "Hello"};
dynamic itemClassName = AppendClassName(item);
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(itemClassName);
Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

Edit - this works for all types:

```
private static string GetJsonWrapper<T>(T item)
{
    string typeName = typeof(T).Name;
    string jsonOriginal = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(item);
    return string.Format("{{\"{0}\":{1}}}", typeName, jsonOriginal);
}
```

Comment: Cool! This works. But This means that I will have to return dynamic types from my service instead of "SampleItem". IS there any other way?

Comment: Seems like you'll have to use your own serializer, check out this blog post: http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/